# How do I visualize a 3 dimensional matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, visualize

How do I visualize a 3 dimensional matrix?

[image]

- first dimension is x-coordinate  =  different universities
- second dimension is y-coordinate  =  disciplines or specialties (Physics, Mathematics, Art ...)
- third dimension is color  =  different years
- size of the circles =  number of papers in corresponding  discipline/university

Comment: Does this chart type have a name or is it custom-made? Are you asking how to create a similar type of chart in R? If you know the chart type you can find which package can create it.

Comment: Looks like you also have a 4th dimension in the size of the circles...

Comment: @Rodrigo,  number of papers = the size of the circles;  color = years

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos  , I  want to create a similar type of chart in R, But i do not know which type of chart and  which package can creat it.

Comment: any chance you could give some example data?  Something like `ggplot(data)+geom_point(aes(x=university,y=discipline,colour=year, size=num_papers)` should work ...

Answer (score 2):

Using @alexis_laz's example data:

Reorganize data to be `ggplot2`-friendly:

```
library("reshape2")
mm <- melt(mat)
```

Load packages (including `viridis` for prettier colours):

```
library("ggplot2"); theme_set(theme_bw())
library("viridis")
```

Plot as requested (play with size ranges until you like the result):

```
ggplot(mm)+
    geom_point(aes(x=univ,y=dis,colour=yr, size=value))+
        scale_color_viridis()+
            scale_size(range=c(2,18))
```

[image]
However, `ggplot2` gives you lots of freedom, and I would suggest that you pay attention to the [Cleveland hierarchy](http://sfew.websitetoolbox.com/post/clevelands-graphical-features-hierarchy-4598555), which says that it's hard to distinguish quantitative features plotted by size.  Depending on what comparisons you're most interested in, you might try something like this:

```
library(grid)  ## for unit(), to squash panels
ggplot(mm,aes(x=yr,y=value,colour=univ))+
    geom_point()+geom_line()+
        facet_wrap(~dis)+
            scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1")+
                theme(panel.margin=unit(0,"lines"))
```

[image]

(Of course, the data look like a mess because they're randomly generated ...)

Comment: the code is very cool, be sure to learn.  thank you very much .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have data like:

```
set.seed(911)
mat = tapply(sample(0:200, 5*10*16, TRUE, prob = rev(prop.table(0:200))), 
             expand.grid(univ = paste("univ", 1:5, sep = ""), 
                         dis = paste("dis", 1:10, sep = ""), 
                         yr = 2000:2015), 
             I)
```

You could try something along the lines of:

```
#convert to easy to manipulate format            
DF = as.data.frame(as.table(mat))

#x
xlvs = unique(DF$univ)
xx = match(DF$univ, xlvs)

#y
ylvs = unique(DF$dis)
yy = match(DF$dis, ylvs)

#colors
collvs = unique(DF$yr)
cols = terrain.colors(length(collvs), alpha = 0.75)[match(DF$yr, collvs)]

#sizes
maxcex = 5
cexs = (DF$Freq * maxcex) / max(DF$Freq)


layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), nrow = 1))
#plot 1
plot(xx, yy, col = cols, cex = cexs, pch = 19, axes = FALSE, frame.plot = TRUE)
axis(1, at = seq_along(xlvs), labels = xlvs)
axis(2, at = seq_along(ylvs), labels = ylvs, las = 1)   

#plot 2 
par(mar = c(1, 1, 1, 4))
fill = terrain.colors(length(collvs) * 9, alpha = 0.75)  #higher 'resolution' of plot
barplot(matrix(rep_len(1L, length(fill))), col = fill, border = NA, axes = FALSE)
axis(4, at = seq(1, length(fill), 9) + 4, labels = collvs, las = 1)
```

Which gives:
[image]

Comment: thank you @alexis_laz,  you are a very warm-hearted person,

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
fulldata <- read.csv(...) # your data.frame
colors=c(...) # create your color array here
plot(NULL,xlim=1:9,ylim=1:20) # just to define the area of the graph
abline(v=1:9,h=1:20) # the axis inside the graph
for (y in 2013:2002) {
    data <- fulldata[which(fulldata$year == y),]
    circle(data$university,data$discipline,size=data$numberofpapers,col=year[y-2001])
}
axis(...) # or mtext or whatever to put the labels on the axis
```

Comment: I'm eager to have a demo for visualizing a 4 dimensional matrix

Answer (score 0):

====================data============

num univ    dis paper   cited   year

1   Beijing Physics 193 4555    2005

2   Beijing Physics 197 2799    2006

3   Beijing Physics 240 2664    2007

4   Beijing Physics 200 3191    2008

5   Beijing Physics 268 2668    2009

6   Beijing Physics 249 2300    2010

7   Beijing Physics 262 2080    2011

8   Beijing Physics 230 2371    2012

9   Beijing Physics 309 1367    2013

10  Beijing Physics 284 615 2014

11  Beijing Chemistry   143 1650    2005

12  Beijing Chemistry   149 2379    2006

13  Beijing Chemistry   190 2566    2007

14  Beijing Chemistry   147 1888    2008

15  Beijing Chemistry   184 2146    2009

16  Beijing Chemistry   214 2568    2010

## ---

```
  mm <- read.table("data.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "", encoding='UTF-8')

  library("ggplot2")
  theme_set(theme_bw())
  library("viridis")

  ggplot(mm)+
  geom_point(aes(x=univ,y=dis,colour=year, size=paper))+
  scale_color_viridis()+
  scale_size(range=c(2,18))
```

==========================================================
but, the year becomes  2005.0 2007.5 2010.0 2012.5 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRGZT.png)

Comment: @Ben Bolker, please give me some help